# I can not put single double quotes ' " ' in a string for regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build regex pattern but the string doesn't take single double quotes.

this is the pattern and it crashes when I add **\"**

```
@"(?<\"|\'|\“)(?'first'{0}\s(?'middle'{0}{1}{2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In an `@` string literal, you need to use `""` to escape double quotes:

```
@"(?<\""|\'|\“)(?'first'{0}\s(?'middle'{0}{1}{2}"
```

Comment: But I don't need both opening and closing. I need only one of them because this is what I am aiming in my Regex template.

Comment: That is not an opening and closing quote. That string there only contains one double-quote character, which is escaped.